# 403 disallowed user agent using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I am getting 403 disallowed user agent. My mobile app is calling our asp.net application where we are calling google for oauth2 
authentication. Since this is now not allowed how do i resolve the 403 error. Google docs suggest some libraries which will help in resolving this error (https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html). But our application is calling an asp.net application which in turn calls https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token. My question is how to implement those libraries in our asp.net application?

Comment: http code 403 is unauthorized, chech the authentication code

Comment: @bradbury9 He mentions the error says `disallowed user agent`.

Comment: Below is the exact error:This user-agent is not permitted to make an OAuth authorization request to 
Google as it is classified as an embedded user-agent (also known as a 
web-view). 

Per our policy, only browsers are permitted to make authorization requests 
to Google. 

We offer several libraries and samples for native apps to perform 
authorization requests in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use [Google API Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/) and here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) of how to use it. 403 error code means you are not authorized, check thoroughly your authorization process

Comment: The Google API Nuget package you suggested works only on .net framework 4.5+. I tried installing in my application but I wasn't successful because the project targets .net 4.0 framework. My application uses  Google 2 factor Authentication on the app. It used to work previously but now  as per google " we will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views”. Hence, our existing code is not working. You can refer the link https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html.

Comment: @Ganesh there is an older package, that supports .net 4.0 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/1.10.0
Try specifiying version 1.10.0 it is the last package with .net 4.0 support